# mPDF: workaround for heading [h1-hx] margins in table

Tags: mpdf

**Question:**

How can I add margins and/or paddings to headings (h1 - h4) that are part of a `TD` or `TH`?

**Current Situation:**

I have a pre-generated HTML document that is being generated by JIRA. The structure of this document is as follows:

```
<tr class="rowAlternate">
  <td class="jira-macro-table-underline-pdfexport">
    <h1><a name="StandardizedInterface"></a>Standardized Interface</span></h1>
    <h2><a name="ShortDescription"></a>Short Description</h2>
    <ul> ... </ul>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I programmatically extend this document with `<tocentry>` and other mPDF-specific elements so it can be used as a handout, the generated PDF looks quite good but there is one major issue I have with headings in tables.

This is how the document shows up in the browser:

> [image: As shown in browser]

Inside generated PDF:

> [image: Inside PDF]

As can be see the margins of the headings have disappeared in the PDF export. All my tests with adding inline CSS to the headings or to wrap them with other elements have failed so far. 
The [mPDF documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/tables/tables.html) says:

> Block-level tags (DIV, P etc) are ignored inside tables, including any
>   CSS styles.

This will most likely mean that this can't be done with pure CSS or wrapping.

I hope that someone else encountered this problem before and could share some insights as how to achieve spacing around block elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Workaround / solution

I used a workaround that solved the problem in my case by using `preg_replace_callback()` that I needed anyways to format my document properly. Whenever the callback handles a heading, I add a transparent image right after the text of the heading whose height I define by doing a bit of math.

### Code

```php
function formatHeading($p) {

  // I only want headings for h1-h3:
  $tocEntry= '';
  if (is_numeric($p[2]) &&  $p[2] >= 1 && $p[2] <= 3) {
    $tocEntry= "<tocentry level=\"{$p[2]}\" content=\"{$p[3]}\" />";
  }

  // calculates the heights of the vertical spacer
  $spacerHeight= ((6-$p[2]) * 10);

  return
  "{$p[1]}{$tocEntry} {$p[3]} {$p[4]}
   <img src=\"../assets/images/transparent.png\" height=\"{$spacerHeight}\" style=\"vertical-align:middle;\" width=\"1\" border=\"0\"/>";
}

// Matches e.g. "<h2><a name="SimpleTest"></a>Simple test</h2>"
$buffered= preg_replace_callback('|(<h(\d)+>?<a?[\w\s\d="%>]+<\/a>)(.+?[\s\r\n\']*.*)(<\/h\d+>)|',
  "formatHeading", $buffered);
```

### Result

To illustrate the position of the spacer I used a non-transparent image to generate the PDF:

> [image: Sample showing formatted headings]

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to convert the mark-up to a format similar to the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="h1">Report</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="h2">Description</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Body</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can then apply appropriate padding to the `<td>` elements by targeting the class name:

```
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: none;
}

td.h1 {
    padding: 30px 0;
}

td.h2 {
    padding: 15px 0;
}
</style>
```

[Use a DOM parser like the one from Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) to help you traverse your current mark-up and rebuild it in the proper format automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation but as I don't know the document structure that I'll receive I can't simply convert everything. There may be cases where I receive a table, a table containing tables, a page without any tables at all. I figured out a way though that works in my case, will add it as an answer to this question. Thanks again for your thoughts!